# How do I splice a directory into a char * containing a pathname in C?

Tags: c, string, unix, char

So right now I'm trying to splice in a directory name into the middle of a pathname.

For example, say I want to splice in DIRNAME right after where OTHERDIRNAME occurs in the path. For example, let's say the path is:

```
/home/user/folder/OTHERDIRNAME/morefolders/test/etc
```

My goal is to get a new pathname that looks like this:

```
/home/user/folder/OTHERDIRNAME/DIRNAME/morefolders/test/etc
```

By the way, I have the variables for holding the old pathname and the name of the directory where I want the new directory spliced into. So I just need help using str functions in C to try and actually splice DIRNAME in at the right location. I've tried using strtok, but I seem to run into issues using OTHERDIRNAME as the delimeter, as I think that the delimeter argument needs to be a single character...

Comment: The delimiter *argument* is a string, but `strtok` will only use one char from it (the first one it finds), hence it's called the delimiter *set*.

Comment: I have given an answer using `strtok`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[128] = "/home/user/folder/OTHERDIRNAME/morefolders/test/etc";
    char* delim = "/";
    char* tok;
    char buf[128];

    tok = strtok(str,delim);
    strcpy(buf,"/");
    while(tok)
    {
            strcat(buf,tok);
            strcat(buf,"/");
            if(strcmp(tok,"OTHERDIRNAME") == 0)
            {
                    strcat(buf,"DIRNAME");
                    strcat(buf,"/");
            }

            tok = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }

    printf("Dir path: %s\n", buf);
}
```

**Output**

```
Dir path: /home/user/folder/OTHERDIRNAME/DIRNAME/morefolders/test/etc/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward, although potentially confusing. Use `strstr` to search the source string for your "delimiter". Add the length of the delimiter so we point to the position of the splice. And then 3 `memcpy` calls of the appropriate lengths.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *dir = "/home/user/folder/OTHERDIRNAME/morefolders/test/etc";
    char *seek = "/OTHERDIRNAME/";
    char *ins = "DIRNAME/";
    char *splice_point;
    char *result;

    splice_point = strstr(dir, seek); // points to the first slash we're interested in
    splice_point += strlen(seek);     // now points to the second slash
    result = malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(ins)+1);  // allocate string of appropriate length
    memcpy(result, dir, splice_point - dir);     // copy the head
    memcpy(result + (splice_point - dir), ins, strlen(ins));  // copy the splice
    strcpy(result + (splice_point - dir) + strlen(ins), splice_point);  // copy the tail (and term)

    printf("%s\n", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, strtok will match any single character in the second parameter as a delimiter.

[strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)  should do what you want.

Off the top of my head (uncompiled and untested):

```
// Returns a malloc'd null-terminated string or NULL
char * replaceInString(const char * original, const char * match, const char * replace)
{
    const char * foundMatch = strstr(original, match);
    if (foundMatch)
    {
        ptrdiff_t offset = foundMatch - original;
        int matchLength = strlen(match);
        int replaceLength = strlen(replace);

        char * newString = malloc(strlen(original) + replaceLength - matchLength + 1);
        strncpy(newString, original, offset);
        strcpy(newString + offset, replace);
        strcpy(newString + offset + replaceLength, original + offset + matchLength);

        return newString;
    }
    return NULL;
}

// snip
   char * newDirName = replaceInString(oldDirName, "/OTHERDIRNAME/", "/OTHERDIRNAME/DIRNAME/");
// snip
```

Of course, adapt memory management to your needs. You could do the operation in-place if the buffer is guaranteed to be big enough.